# Java Properties Class appending date

Tags: java, file-io, configuration-files

I am using the java properties class to append a value to my config file with this code.(I stripped out error handling and whatnot)

```
Properties configFile = new Properties();
configFile.setProperty(key, value);
configFile.store(new FileOutputStream("plugins/WirelessRedstone/receivers.properties", true), null);
```

When I append a key value pair, the current date and time is added before my pair. example `#Thu May 26 03:39:59 EDT 2011`.

How can I make this stop?

Thanks a bunch, giodamelio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per Java Docs of store method in Properties..it always writes that line

> Next, a comment line is **always written**, consisting of an ASCII # character, the current date and time (as if produced by the toString method of Date for the current time), and a line separator as generated by the Writer.

you can write your own store method for this.

Comment: Thanks, I don't know how i missed that in the javadocs :|. The fact that is 1:30 could have something to do with it though >.<